# pagination /page/2 after site url issue

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, xenu

When i was generated my site reports with xenu, I have found /page/2 issue. In my reports their is a link with my site name and after /page/2 link.

Example: http://www.test.com/page/2

I have used pagination in custom post type "blog". So My pagination link is  "http://www.test.com/blog/page/2". But currently reports gave "http://www.test.com/page/2" this url.

Comment: Where did that link appear? Could it be a link you put up manually? Do you have any caching plugin activated which might still serve the old response (from before changing the siteurl)?

Comment: That link not appear or put anywhere but it comes from xenu.

Comment: We are talking about `Xenu's Link Sleuth`, aren't we? If yes, xenu found that link somewhere on your page and checked whether it is accessible. You should be able to see the source of the broken link.